# Getting position in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I want to make a navigation bar with javascript that changes the position to fixed after you scrolled down to some point and makes it relative after scrolling up. If I just do it fixed, it messes up the banner. How can I keep track where the user is on the scrolling position?

Comment: Plz, share your code!

Comment: I can't seem to copy paste html code or css .I don't have a javascript code yet.

Comment: At least try something. We are not going to write code for you. First try, research and then ask if you are not able to do something.

Comment: I didn't want you to compeletly write my code, my question is how can I keep track of user position in scrollbar

Comment: I would send the link of my website but I think that counts as advertising

Comment: You can share the link..

Comment: http://cemoner.lovestoblog.com/

Comment: My goal is making the position fixed after a certain point. I know how to do that but I don't know how to make a move after a certain scrolling point

Comment: Im very new to javascript so I don't know a lot

Comment: I am making an example 

Comment: Should I send the link of the site that I got the idea from?

Comment: Why not, then i will have an good idea.

Comment: https://www.airbus.com/ here you can see that when you are at the top of the page, It is no longer position:fixed

Comment: There is a non js or you can say just css, should I share that or you want js one!

Comment: Could you send both If you have it, If you don't js pls :D

Comment: I am writing the answers 

Comment: Oh okay. But if you could just tell me how to track the movement, I can do the rest myself :D

Comment: Yea they are just that!/ Hint

Comment: I have added an answer, If you don't understand something let me know ✌

Comment: Thank you sir. Do you have a discord account or something that maybe I can ask questions later?

Comment: Discord: Manas Khandelwal#5460 Email: mkdpsj@gmail.com 

Comment: I have also added some links to Documentation, you should read them, they are far better than my explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this...

#### 1) Pure CSS

You can use the `position` `sticky`.

```css
body {
  /*  Just added, so you can scroll on page */
  height: 200vh;
}

#box {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

- [`position` Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

---

#### 2) Javascript

Here we are adding a scroll event, which will get fired when we scroll.

`this.scrollY` indirectly means `window.scrollY`, and it returns the position of our scrollbar. `box.scrollHeight` returns the height required to reach the `box`.

Ans we are comparing them and when they meet our conditions we add `.fixed` class to the `#box`.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (this.scrollY >= box.scrollHeight) box.classList.add("fixed");
  else box.classList.remove("fixed");
});
```

```css
body {
  /*  Just added, so you can scroll on page */
  height: 200vh;
}

#box {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

#box.fixed {
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

- [scroll event Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)
- [scrollY Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
- [scrollHeight Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

---